# I'm new at programming. I'm not sure how much to use methods

Tags: java, methods

So, I just finished my first program, but I haven't use any methods in it, since I'm just beginning to learn how to use them. Here's the original code : http://codepad.org/JiBfJI8Q I started to fractionate it but realised that it would be a method inside another all the way down. Is that actually the way to do it, or did I get the idea wrong?

Comment: I do not think that SO is the right place for such questions since an answer would be too long. If you take classes in programming, ask your instructor/teacher/prof. If you are an autodidact you should start with [the basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html). A tutorial dedicated on methods can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

Comment: I have like 90 minutes of lessons once a week and there are 10 more stundents (which are not interested in the class at all btw, they are just there because it's compulsory) that the teacher has to help. I did understand how methods work, I just need someone to teach me how and where I should use them

Comment: Everywhere. Whenever you think a piece of code could be reusable, pack it in a method and call the method instead.

Comment: Also please be aware that programming has specialized vocabulary to describe certain actions and processes. "fractionate" is not one of those (I assume you meant "refactor"?). And if by "method inside another all the way down" you mean that one method calls another, then yes, that is indeed often a good code design choice.

Comment: I see, sorry for not being used to the programming jargon, I guess I'll learn it through time and experience. So if a piece of code won't be repeated there's no point on doing a method for it right?

Comment: There is always the argument of readability to be made: if you separate your code within smaller methods that do one dedicated job, it is easier to read (and therefore to debug) your code, especially for others.

Comment: I see. I'll try to make all of this advice work then, thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without having looked at your code:
The general idea of methods is to separate small
 portions of code which might be used at multiple other places in your code.

so yes, calling methods from within other methods is a good thing to do.
ideally your so called "composed methods" read out like a little story:

```
public void transaction(){
   openDatabaseConnection();
   addRecordsToDatabase();
   closeDataseConnection();
}
```